# bash script not seeing a file

Tags: linux, bash

Can anyone explain to me why this isn't working?

`ls ~\` does show that `cheatsheet` is in the home directory

```
  1 #! /bin/bash
  2         let i=0
  3         cheatsheet="~/cheatsheet"
  4         until [ $i -eq $# ]
  5         do
  6                 grep -e $"$i" -e "^\s" $cheatsheet
  7                 i=$(expr $i + 1 )
  8         done    
  9         if [ -z $1  ]
 10         then 
 11                 grep -e "^\w" $cheatsheet
 12         fi
```

Comment: `~` is not processed when expanding variables.

Comment: Also, you can't use `$"$i"` to access parameter `i`. You need to use variable indirection: `${!i}`

Comment: @Barmar I never knew that actually, thanks

Comment: I think it's better to use `while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do ...; shift; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`cheatsheet = "$HOME/cheatsheet"`

Note: `~` cannot be used in variables.

Answer (score 1):

Tilde doesn't expand in a double quoted variable context. You could use `$HOME` like

```
cheatsheet="$HOME/cheatsheet"
```